# Framer / React: Can't change focus state of Text Input onClick / onChangePage

Tags: reactjs, framerjs

This is a Framer/React question:

I have a bunch of text fields in a "page" component and I want the focus to shift on every "page" change.

There's a button controlling the pager but no trigger (onPageChange / onClick) is changing the attribute of "focus" on the relevant text input.

This is the code I tried using to change the value of foc2 (the focus attribute) to true
When I manually change it to true it works, but in this case it doesn't

```
export function Page(): Override {
return {
    currentPage: state.page,
    onChangePage: (index) => {
        state.page = index
        state.foc2 = true
    },
}
```

}[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you have more complete code you could share?

Make sure you set the state to the index of the current focused input, and use that to change the `currentPage` property.

Happy to help if you send more context, you can also find more help in Framer's community at https://framer.com/r/discord